# Now() is giving an error

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am getting an error in the below code.

```
Dim CurrentTime As Date
CurrentTime = Format(Now(), "hh:mm AM/PM")
If CurrentTime = ActiveSheet.Range("I1") Then
    Call SendEMail
End If
```

When the time is right, then the macro is debugging and `Now` is highlighted.
Could anyone solve this problem?

Comment: I think that `Format` returns a string. Can you try `Dim CurrentTime as String` and see what that does?

Comment: This works for me in Excel 2013. What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: LOL, the outlook has this feature built in, for cases you want to send emails late at night (so your boss thinks you are working around the clock)

Comment: Dias by the way, this is the wrong way to automate an email

Comment: Shai Rado, LOL. This email is for follow up purpose, if there is no feedback in 3 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting an actual error are you? It is just not working as expected.

Matt Cremeens has identified your issue I believe, you have declared `CurrentTime` as a date data type. A date data type stores a *number* representing a time/date, however you are asking for it to store string information (AM/PM) too which is can't so it is getting stripped out.

The results is cell one may hold a value like '10:30 AM' but the `Format(Now(), "hh:mm AM/PM")` code going into the `Date` variable is resulting in '10:30:00', so the two are never matching as strings. Copy as Matt has suggested and this should work (`Dim CurrentTime As String`).

Better yet, use the date comparison function `DateDiff`:-

```
If DateDiff("s",ActiveSheet.Range("I1"),Time()) > 0 then
    SendEmail
End If
```

This is saying if the time now is greater than the value in `I1` (to the second) then run `SendEmail`.

Comment: `CurrentTime = Format(Now(), "hh:mm AM/PM")` gives `10:56:00 AM` in Excel 2013 even when you declare it as `Date` :)

Comment: But `CurrentTime` is not storing the AM/PM part specifically, that is a formatting thing, it holds the value only and then your code/environment defines how that value is interpreted/shown.

Comment: True. I am not saying that your suggestion of comparison of time with worksheet is incorrect. I am agreeing with you. I even in fact voted you as well. All I am saying that when you debug `Format(Now(), "hh:mm AM/PM")`, it will give you `10:56:00 AM` and not `10:30:00` as mentioned in your post.

Comment: Ah ok. I think that may be a machine locale based format as mine did give `10:30:00`, either that or another subtle difference between office versions!

Comment: You are getting "HH:MM"SS" only because in your `Regional Setting`, Long Time is set as `HH:MM:SS`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the environment to test the solution right now but from what I remember you don't need the brackets in 2007 and also you don't need the format.

Try the following code and see if that fits your need:

If **Hour(Now)** = ActiveSheet.Range("I1") Then

(...)

End If